# Confusion in differential of enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics

We define enthalpy of system as $$H=U+PV$$

Clearly enthalpy of a system is a function of temperature and pressure that is $$H=f(P,T)$$

Therefore we have $$ dH=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_PdT +\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_T dP$$

Clearly for a substance first term is equal to $nC_P\Delta T $ while second term depends on nature of substance, it is zero for an ideal gas as well as for a real gas undergoing an isobaric process.

My book (Wiley's Physical chemistry) mentions that it is approximately zero for solids and liquids but why ?

Here is a screenshot from my book[image]

Comment: Is there any context for this statement? It is hard to argue something in general. I would begin with solids and liquids being (almost) incompressible, but this is clearly not enough.

Comment: @user3725600 Which statement are you talking about?

Comment: "My book mentions that it is approximately zero for solids..." Does your book say that in general $dH$ is very small for solids and liquids or only in some specific conditions?

Comment: What book is that?

Comment: @user3725600 edited

Comment: Wiley is a publisher with many books titled *Physical Chemistry*; who is the author?

Answer (score 0):

Since $dH=T\,dS+V\,dP$,

$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_T=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T+V=-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P+V=-T\alpha V+V=V(1-\alpha T),$$

where I've used a Maxwell relation and where $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient. The book is asserting that $1-\alpha T$ is negligible for condensed matter.